# How does Ozone disinfect water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, water, water-treatment, ozone

How does ozone remove the impurities in water? I know that there is a process which some European countries use water purification systems based on ozone. It would be beneficial if you could provide with some chemical equations to describe the process of how impurities are removed in water.

Answer (score 5):

Ozone is a powerful oxidizer (redox potential of 2.07) and will kill bacteria and destroy viruses (not sure if I can say it kills viruses) by transferring oxygen atoms to them. It also decomposes in water forming OH radicals, which quickly oxidize organic and inorganic compounds. Ozone can also react by ozonolysis, breaking compounds which have double or triple bonds into smaller molecules, some of which will act as oxidizers themselves.

The chemical equation (mechanism) for ozonolysis is as follows:
[image]